# Why use NSCoding in UITableViewController get error?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I use NSCoding to store the data persistence 
this is my code

```
class CenterRecordTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   private var records:[ReplayListData] = []

   override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
      super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
      aCoder.encodeObject(self.records, forKey: "records")
   }

   required  init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      if let res = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("records") as? [ReplayListData] {
         self.records = res
      }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      loadLocalData()
      if records.count > 0 {
          getDataFromServer()
      }
   }

   func loadLocalData(){
        if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("CenterRecords") as? NSData {
            let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! CenterRecordTableViewController
            self.records = obj.records
        }
    }

    func saveLocalData(){
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "CenterRecords")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func getDataFromServer(){
         //get data from server
        saveLocalData()
    }

}
```

But When I run the application , The error is hppen in

`aCoder.encodeObject(self.records, forKey: "records")`

this is console output:

```
2015-09-19 13:09:57.219 test[41108:3488786] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x182651f0 of class 'test.ReplayListData' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[test.ReplayListData replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
```

**EDIT**

this is the code of ReplayListData  I have removed other variables

```
class ReplayListData {
    var created:Int
    init(a:Int){
        self.created = a
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

I try to inheritance the `NSObject` in `ReplayListData`

```
class ReplayListData：NSObject {
   var created:Int
   init(a:Int){
       self.created = a
   }
}
```

The application crash too ,but the console is change

```
[test.ReplayListData encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17173970
2015-09-19 13:34:14.407 test[41238:3492144] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[test.ReplayListData encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17173970'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2431cd67 0x31dbdc77 0x2432222d 0x24320109 0x24251938 0x24fc0425 0x24fc162f 0x24fc1c11 0x24fc0425 0x258d30 0x258eb8 0x24fc0425 0x24fc67c1 0x2599c8 0x25fa58 0x28b328 0x1a8f9cb 0x1a8f9b7 0x1a93411 0x242e2c41 0x242e1361 0x2422e981 0x2422e793 0x2b5af051 0x27820981 0x312da8 0x32359aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Could you show how `ReplayListData` was implemented?

Comment: Why would you archive a view controller? You should only archive data.

Comment: I'm learning How to use NSCoding  @rmaddy

Comment: That's fine but why are you arching a view controller. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Really? I only want to try it  @rmaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your class `ReplayListData` like this

```
class ReplayListData: NSObject {
    var created:Int
    init(a:Int){
        self.created = a
    }
}
```

Comment: I must achieve `encodeWithCoder` and `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)`  protocol in ReplayListData?  @Ducky

Comment: I add the two protocol in ReplayListData It works fine